# how to upload image by using asiformdatarequest

Tags: ios, image-uploading, asiformdatarequest

I intend to upload image to server using asiformdatarequest.my code like:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testicon.jpg"];
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 0.5)];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:ADDRESS,myType,action]];

    ASIFormDataRequest *currentRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [currentRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
    [currentRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"multipart/form-data"];
    [currentRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [currentRequest setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"user_id"];


    NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseString);
```

but the server don't return correct result.what' s the problem it might be?

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting data-

```
[currentRequest setData:imgData forKey:@"file"];
```